# Creating MySQL Table not working

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I don't understand where my error in this code to create a simple Table in a MySQL database is:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "administrator", "199992", "test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Select DB
mysqli_select_db($con, "test");

// Create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notizen(Benutzer TEXT,Datum TEXT,Notiz TEXT)";
```

This should actually work, shouldn't it?
But when I try to insert something later:

```
if(!(empty($_POST[vorname]) and empty($_POST[nachname]) and empty($_POST[notiz]))) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO Notizen (Benutzer, Datum, Notiz)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[vorname] $_POST[nachname]', 'datum', '$_POST[notiz]')"; 

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
 }
}
```

I get an error:

> "Error: Table 'test.notizen' doesn't exist".

Comment: Are you running your CREATE statement? Are you checking for errors after you do?

Comment: So you have a text string saying create table.... where are you running it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As I see in your code, you are not executing the create query. execute it by `mysqli_query($con,$sql)`.
2. Give the space between `Notizen (Benutzer` table name and braces in create table query.
3. Check that your query is executing or not by using the error function to create table.

Comment: I am very sorry, I'm only a beginner and I only noticed now that
 `$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notizen(Benutzer TEXT,Datum TEXT,Notiz TEXT)";` 
is only a string and needs `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` to run!

Answer (score 2):

make sure you run the query with mysqli_query() .. you cant insert before the table definition is stored in your db

Answer (score 2):

After this line

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notizen(Benutzer TEXT,Datum TEXT,Notiz TEXT)";
```

You must run a

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "Error creating a database: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```